# How do I use a U2F token when adding a Google account to my Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, security, accounts

I'm enrolled in Google's Advanced Protection Program, which means I can only authenticate with a physical FIDO U2F token on every sign-in.

Trouble is, that when I try using my Google account, I see "You can only use your Security Keys with Google Chrome".

[image: Image of User Accounts]

Is there a way around this, or a way for me to use my U2F security key here?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to use your U2F token in this scenario.  U2F depends on browser support, and as of August 2018, only Chrome, Firefox and Opera support it.

As a workaround, you could set up Google Authenticator and use that to log in.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to set up Google Authenticator, since ‘after you enroll, other authentication factors you might be used to, like codes sent via SMS or the Google Authenticator app, will no longer work.’ [Google Advanced Protection Program](https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/)

Comment: It still should be possible to add a non-U2F second factor.  Go to your Google account settings -> Sign in and Security -> Signing into Google -> 2-Step Verification and there should be an option to add Google Authenticator or other methods.

Comment: @thirtyseven unfortunately, no, the Google Advanced Protection Program does not allow you to add a non-U2F second-factor of authentication :(

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the issue you described and I saw on Google's [Advanced Protection Program Page](https://landing.google.com/advancedprotection/), and read that

> Apple’s Mail, Calendar, and Contacts apps will continue to be able to access your Google data as normal.

[image: Screenshot of Google Advanced Protection website]

So, that means you should be able to use your U2F key on that application. I would contact Google or just turn off advanced protection program, then re-activate it.

Also, make sure you are on the latest version of MacOS (which is High Sierra 10.13.6 or Mojave 10.14) because that could be the reason why it is not working.

I hope this answer helps

Comment: Turning off the advanced protection programme and reactivating it does not fix the problem. However, it's *possible* that updating MacOS to the latest version might fix it; I am running Yosemite (10.10.5), but am not able to update for other reasons. I would be interested to learn whether updating the Mac OS fixes the issue for other users who are able to update.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help in my case. I'm on macOS High Sierra and have been since I activated Advanced Protection. I read this notice, or something similar, but I still couldn't get it to work. It's likely that this behavior is limited to iOS and not MacOS.

Comment: Okay. So I guess we still don't have an answer for this...

Comment: Mojave latest doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible as of macOS Catalina 10.15.2, as Safari has gained support for security keys. When signing in to your Google account in the Internet Accounts preference pane, Safari will prompt you to touch your USB security key after you enter your Google account password, and will then prompt you to allow macOS access to your Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Google *seems to think* they have a solution (though it's not directly linked to the ***Advanced Protection*** [Common Questions](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7539956#non-goog_ios), and *doesn't help* in the case of ***Advanced Protection*** ) - because **App Passwords** are not available to *Advanced Protection* users.

All other articles about "Trusted Devices", etc. lead you down a rabbit whole of loops to "Checking Your Security Settings".

[image: Sign in with an Apple Device]

[image: App Password unavailable]